# Grab the Memory Usage Value from Pandas DataFrame.info()

Tags: pandas

How can I grab the memory usage value (displayed in the output of the funciton `DataFrame.info()` and assign to a variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DataFrame.memory_usage().sum()`

There's an example on [this page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/faq.html):

```
In [8]: df.memory_usage()
Out[8]: 
Index                 72
bool                5000
complex128         80000
datetime64[ns]     40000
float64            40000
int64              40000
object             40000
timedelta64[ns]    40000
categorical         5800
dtype: int64

# total memory usage of dataframe
In [9]: df.memory_usage().sum()
Out[9]: 290872
```

Looking at the source code of df.info() shows that using memory_usage() is how they compute the actual memory usage in df.info():

```
... <last few lines of def info from pandas/frame.py>
    mem_usage = self.memory_usage(index=True, deep=deep).sum()
    lines.append("memory usage: %s\n" %
                 _sizeof_fmt(mem_usage, size_qualifier))
_put_lines(buf, lines)
```

Answer (score 4):

As [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) says we should have a `buffer`.

`buf : writable buffer, defaults to sys.stdout`

For `df`

```
import io
impor pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'someCol' : ["foo", "bar"]
}) 
buf = io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buf)
info = buf.getvalue()
print(info)
```

Gives me output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
someCol    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

For specific memory usage value:

```
info = buf.getvalue().split('\n')[-2]
print(info)
```

Would give the output:

```
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I never remember how to `.getvalue()` from the buffer. Maybe add this to your answer to complete it full-circle: `buf.getvalue().split('\n')[-2]`